# What is the value of $43^{1234567890} \mod 22$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can one find out the value of $43^{1234567890} \mod 22\;?$

Can I just say that because $123456890$ is an even number I can calculate $43^2 \mod 22$, which is $1$?

Comment: Well, I'd point out first that $43 \equiv -1 \mod 22$. And $-1$ raised to an even power equals 1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289137/calculate-201234567-mod-251?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be true, but the way you phrase it seems a bit wrong.

So, just to avoid any confusion, you can calculate $43^2 \pmod {22}$ but only because $43 \equiv -1 \pmod {22}$ and ${(-1)}^n = {(-1)}^2$ for every even n.

In other words, $42^{1234567890} \equiv 42^2 \pmod {22}$ would have been false

Comment: $43^{1234567890} \equiv 43^2 \pmod{22}$ is perfectly correct. Whether an instructor would accept it without further justification is another story.

Comment: @fkraiem It is indeed totally correct, I just wanted to be sure OP only use it when they're allowed. As for the instructor part, it's mainly opinion biaised, but my former math teachers wouldn't have accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that’s fine, it suffices use that

$$a \equiv b \mod m \implies a^n \equiv b^n \mod m$$

and in that case $43 \equiv -1 \mod {22}$.